# Python space invaders game trying to compare the x-coordinates of all enemies to wall's

Tags: python, function, if-statement, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am making a space invaders clone, and I am trying to implement enemy wall collision, but I cant seem to compare all the x coordinates to the wall(I drew all the enemies using turtle and put them in a list) I am getting the error (if enemies_coordinates[i] > -280:IndexError: list index out of range) which confuses me because I am appending the enemies coordinates to the enemies_coordinates list yet it only outputs one. I am probably doing something weird, any help is appreciated.

```
#FIXME Check the cordainates of all enemies for wall collison
def enemy_coor():
    i = 0
    for alien in enemies:
        global enemies_coordinates
        enemies_coordinates = []
        enemies_coordinates.append(enemies[i].xcor())
        print(enemies_coordinates)
        i += 1

#FIXME Wall collioson
def alien_wall_collison():
    i = 0
    for alien in enemies:
        print(i)
        if enemies_coordinates[i] > -280:
            print("turn Right")
        i += 1
```

Comment: you are resetting the `enemies_coordinates` to a new list in every loop inside `enemy_coor` so it will always be in length of 1 eventually...

Comment: really? I was trying to cycle though the entire list with it and then reset it after the for loop, how can I change the code to do that? Edit oh I see nevermind I see it, thank you lol

Comment: I've added an answer I hope it will make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your errors is that you reset the `enemies_coordinates` with every loop in `enemy_coor`.  I'll suggest a code without this bug, I've also used enumeration for better programming habbits, and in general I don't encourage you to use globals but I stick to your current implementation.

```
enemies_coordinates = []

def enemy_coor():
   global enemies_coordinates
   for alien in enemies:
       enemies_coordinates.append(alien.xcor())
       print(enemies_coordinates)

def alien_wall_collison():
    for i, alien in enumerate(enemies):
        if enemies_coordinates[i] > -280:
            print("turn Right")
```

Answer (score 0):

your appending the values to the enemies_coordinates = [] but your not defined the enemies or you can try this enemies_coordinates.append(alien[i].xcor()) instead of doing that after defining the enemies

and decrease the value of if condition